# ORACLE getting Dates with 3 letters

Tags: java, database, oracle

I have a program that inserts some data into a table.

In my table im showing day and week number like the following output (in danish)

*TO Uge 42*

Where TO is the name of the day

Uge is week

and 42 is the number of the week.

What i would like to do is get the TO to be TOR(Short for Torsdagwhich is the danish word for Thursday)

My Code looks like this at the moment:

```
"DY' || ' ' || '\"Uge\" '|| 'IW";
```

Are there any whay in Orcle where i can get the date as a 3 lettered String or do i have to make substrings of the string and change it?

**UPDATE ADDED SQL CODE FROM MY PROGRAM**

```
String sql =
            "SELECT                                                                     " +
            "   TO_CHAR(MIN(TIDSPUNKT),'"+getDateDescriptionFormat(when)+"') AS PERIOD, " +
            "   NVL(QUEUE,' ') AS QUEUE,                                                " +
            "   NVL(SUM(ANTAL_KALD),0) AS CALLS,                                        " +
            "   NVL(SUM(ANTAL_BESVARET),0) AS ANSWERED_CALLS,                           " +
            "   NVL(SUM(BESVARET_25_SEK),0) AS ANSWERED_CALLS_25_SEC,                   " +
            "   NVL(SUM(INTERN_KALD),0) AS INTERNAL_CALLS                               " +
            "FROM                                                                       " +
            "   KS_DRIFT.PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT                                           " +
            "WHERE                                                                      " +
            "   TIDSPUNKT >= '"+getStartDate(start,when)+"' AND                         " +
            "   TIDSPUNKT <= '"+ slut+"' AND                                            " +
            "   TO_CHAR(TIDSPUNKT,'DY') NOT IN ('AB')                                   " +
            "GROUP BY                                                                   " +
            "   TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT,'"+getDateFormatString(when)+"'),                       " +
            "   QUEUE                                                                   " +
            "ORDER BY                                                                   " +
            "   PERIOD
```

**THE getDateDiscribtionFormat:**

```
private String getDateDescriptionFormat(char when){
        if (when == 'D')return "DY' || ' ' || '\"Uge\" '|| 'IW";
        if (when == 'W')return "\"Uge\" '||'IW";
        if (when == 'M')return "Mon.' || ' ' || 'YYYY";
        if (when == 'Y')return "YYYY";
        return null;
    }
```

Do note that I DID not make this code my former co worker did and it is messy !

Comment: Very messy, indeed.  Time to refactor.  Don't perpetuate this smell.

Comment: Among the other things you should change is to use bind variables instead of concatenating dates into the SQL query -- which causes one implicit conversion to text when doing the concatenation and a second implicit conversion back to date when the query is executed.  If the session's default date format were to change you could get failures or wrong results, plus you're hard-parsing a new query for every different date it runs for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no other format model that will do what you want.  'DY' gives the "abbreviated name of day" -- in my English-language system this means a three-letter abbreviation, but I guess in your language the standard abbreviation is two letters.

Rather than doing a substring, I'd suggest converting to a numeric day of the week and then simply having a mapping, for example (using English abbreviations):

```
CASE TO_CHAR(sysdate,'D')
  WHEN 1 THEN 'SUN'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'MON'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'TUE'
  <et cetera>
END
```

Comment: Careful with this, 'D' will return 1 for monday in many non-USA locations (dependent upon `NLS_TERRITORY`)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should save a `Date` in a `DATE` column and leave all that other stuff for rendering.  Those are display issues.

Query for a `java.sql.Date` and use `java.text.DateFormat` to turn it into whatever String you want.

Comment: It looks like there is already a `DATE` column, `TIDSPUNKT`, and he is just trying to set the format when getting its value in a query.  But you are probably right that if the point is to pull this data into some front-end for display, doing the conversion to text there may make more sense.

Comment: Right, it makes no sense to me to embed any of this in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MON-DD') from dual;
```

Comment: The problem is that the code is really messy and its a huge work cleaning it up (i did not create the code)

So what he does is the following statement: im going to update my original post